# javascript for opera browser - delete session cookies & reload page

Tags: javascript, opera

I'm hoping that it's possible to write a simple bit of user javascript for opera which will: 1) immediately delete/expire all current session cookies and 2) reload the current page after that has been done.

Additionally, I'd like to be able to trigger this script with a custom opera button.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible - or at least, a generic solution is not possible. The reason is that many sites mark their session cookies as "httpOnly" meaning you can not see them from JavaScript.

Additionally, there is no reliable way to tell which ones among the cookies you do see are session cookies. There is a convention, sort of, to make session cookies have upper-case names, but you can't really rely on that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and explanation! Guess it's on to plan B.